# autoGenerateWrapperClass is null react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am writing wrapper for react-native in scala-js

```
  lazy val reactNative = js.Dynamic.global.require("react-native")
  val View = reactNative.View
  val component = ReactNativeB[Unit]("NativeYeah")
          .render(P => {
             reactNative.createElement(View,null)
        }).buildU
  reactNative.AppRegistry.registerComponent("iOSscala", () => component())
```

**Component registered fine** ,but its failing while creating View element!

> null is not a function (evaluating 'autoGenerateWrapperClass(tag)')"

Full stack trace :

```
CTJSLog> "Error: 
 stack: 
  getComponentClassForElement     index.ios.bundle:5894
  validatePropTypes               index.ios.bundle:5634
  createElement                   index.ios.bundle:5681
  renderApplication               index.ios.bundle:33913
  run                             index.ios.bundle:33858
  runApplication                  index.ios.bundle:33880
  jsCall                          index.ios.bundle:7237
  _callFunction                   index.ios.bundle:7484
  applyWithGuard                  index.ios.bundle:877
  guardReturn                     index.ios.bundle:7286
  callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue  index.ios.bundle:7493
 URL: http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle
 line: 5894
 message: null is not a function (evaluating 'autoGenerateWrapperClass(tag)')"
```

while debugging this function

```
function getComponentClassForElement(element) {
  if (typeof element.type === 'function') {
    return element.type;
  }
  var tag = element.type;
  var componentClass = tagToComponentClass[tag];
  if (componentClass == null) {
    tagToComponentClass[tag] = componentClass = autoGenerateWrapperClass(tag);
  }
  return componentClass;
}
```

tag value is ReactElement

Note : the above code works fine in reactjs with div tag / react component.

**Edit : Its issue from scalajs-react builder ,which obeys ReactJS render API not AppRegistry , closing issue.**

Answer (score 4):

You'll see this error message if the component you're trying to render is undefined ([as per this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/253)). What is the value of `component` before you pass it to `registerComponent`?

Comment: i think component is fine ,  component is an instance of ReactComponentU ( un mounted) . while registration  var componentClass = ReactNativeComponent.getComponentClassForElement(
    element
  ); this line executes fine and even i can see component name there . The only part  failing is creating View element i believe!

Comment: Ok then what's the value of View when it gets passed to createElement?

Comment: I got this error when I forgot to add `module.exports = <ComponentName>;` to the end of my file. Unrelated to this question, but maybe helpful for someone else.